# How to solve the issue ERROR 1117 (HY000): Too many columns -

Tags: mysql

I have a table with more than 1400 columns in my DB.

I trying to export that table to another DB with

```
CREATE TABLE tab_name SELECT * FROM tab_name
```

command. But I am facing error like

> ERROR 1117 (HY000): Too many columns

I think it is due to the large number of columns. But, still I am wondering that, the source table created in source DB with these large number of columns.

Is there any solution to export this table to destination DB?

Comment: `I have a table with more than 1400 columns in my DB` <-- this is the real problem, and you should fix it.  I have never seen a business problem in my life which required more than a few hundred columns (and even that is very rare).

Comment: Split your table vertically (sharding) to logical parts with less columns count joined to the "main" part 1:1.

Comment: If you have a problem that uses a sparse-matrix structure, I would recommend you looking into a Columnar data storage system. There are some problems which it is useful to represent 2-dimensional data in a way which is horizontally grouped, and MySQL is not useful in that case.

Comment: It's surprising that this fails when the existing table has 1400 columns - is the db engine different - 'MySQL has hard limit of 4096 columns per table,' 'Storage engines may impose additional restrictions that limit table column count. For example, InnoDB has a limit of 1017' please review manual for other limits https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/column-count-limit.html